# Google directory API - List of modified users

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I need to synchronize the users of a domain with a third party database. 
Using the method [users.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) I can query for the complete list of users. 
With the comlete list I can identify created users and deleted users. I don't find any way identify updated users.

Is there a way to identify updated users?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Users.watch](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/watch). It lets you know of any changes made to users. When changes are made you can update your database.

Comment: It seems that the **watch** method is intended only for [push-notifications](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/push), or not? I can not use push-notifications because my server is not public, did you know an alternative?